# What does (int & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % int do in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, I encountered the following line:

```
e.g.: (1 & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 4
e.g.: (2 & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 5
```

What does it do? I have tried the code, but I couldn't comprehend its purpose or functionality. What is the code trying to check?

Basically, it's `(int & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % int`.

Actual code (from Hadoop training class):

```
public int getPartition(StringPairWritable key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.getLeft().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the context in which this code appear? On its own I don't see the point, since `1 & Integer.MAX_VALUE` is equal to 1., and 1%4 is also 1.

Comment: @Eran ...for positive values only.

Comment: @laune Well, 1 and 2 are positive

Comment: I hope these lines aren't literally copied but examples of values occurring in `(i & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % j`. Otherwise it's a joke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i & Integer.MAX_VALUE` does the same thing as this code:

```
if(i < 0) {
    i = (i + Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
}
```

The `%` is a regular remainder operation.

It's a quick way of ensuring that an integer is positive if you don't care about it's actual value (e.g. if you want to turn random numbers that can be both positive and negative into only positive values).

Comment: How is that any clearer as for the purpose of the code?

Answer (score 4):

The `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. Thus `num & Integer.MAX_VALUE` clears the highest bit in `num`. The `% numReduceTasks` is normal remainder after division by `numReduceTasks`.

This is done to convert the signed number to the non-negative number and then get the evenly distributed value from `0` to `numReduceTasks-1`. Note that if you write `Math.abs(key.getLeft().hashCode()) % numReduceTasks` you may get negative number if `hashCode()` happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` is still `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. So `& Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a safer alternative.

Comment: Java integers are [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement); there is no sign bit.

Comment: @Raniz:  No, there ***very much is*** a sign bit.

Comment: No, doubles and floats have a sign bit, integers just have a negative-valued MSB.

Comment: Seems like it. the actual code itself is supposed to return postive value only.

Comment: @Raniz the MSB is the sign bit. Wikipedia agrees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Comment: @FailedMathematician So think about it: if the return value should be non-negative (which is not the same as positive): why didn't the author `Math.abs(i % j)` ?

Comment: @TimBender: Fair enough, though I still think it's misleading since it implies that flipping it is equal to `i = -i` which is not true for two's complement integers. This answer also implies that this is what the snippet does

Comment: I salvaged my answer, though probably an accept should still go to @Raniz.

Comment: @Raniz, I agree and I flippfed my vote due to the subsequent edits. The first line was correct and sufficient.

Comment: @Raniz regardless of 2's complement, 1's complement of sign-magnitude, the MSbit is always a sign bit and it's used to check for the signness of the value. It's not meant for changing the sign when flipping that bit.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts here:

- What the function actually *does* from a Java perspective, and
- What purpose the function actually *serves*, from a Hadoop perspective.

Let's cover the Java side of it first.  It's fairly straightforward bitwise math, in that it clears the sign bit and turns the value into a positive integer.

That's easy enough to demonstrate here; let's assume that our key is -128876912, which is `0xF8517E90`.  The max value for an int is `0x7FFFFFFF`.

If we look at the actual math operation, the sign bit is cleared (along with quite a few other bits, in this case), and we get a positive integer value.

```
1111 1000 0101 0001 0111 1110 1001 0000
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
---------------------------------------
0111 1000 0101 0001 0111 1110 1001 0000
```

If the value is positive, then the net result is that we get back the same value.

This is important, since a hash code can come back negative; I don't believe that you want a negative value for a reason that's important a bit later.

For the partitioning bit, this is a bit more Hadoop knowledge than I can truly claim, but after [reading the docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html#getPartition(KEY,%20VALUE,%20int)), it informs you which partition the value falls under.  That is where the modulo comes in; you're guaranteed to get a value between `[0, partition)`, thus specifying which reducer the particular bit of data is processed by.

From my reading of it, this is one of the default supplied partitioners, and may not be entirely suitable for your uses (you may want to [group your data in a different way](http://dailyhadoopsoup.blogspot.com/2014/01/partitioning-in-mapreduce.html), for instance).

Answer (score 0):

If the expression in the code is really

```
(i & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % j
```

it computes the residue class of `i mod j`. Note that `i % j` is the remainder of a division, a symmetric (w.r.t. i == 0) function, whereas the residue class, which is a periodic function.

Comment: The code snippet confirms my assumption. The getPartition function maps periodically which might produce a more uniform distribution.